# use of temp table in function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have one table of IP showing multiple values like below

```
IP
192.200.22.173 
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
```

I have another stored procedure which will convert IP to name. Because of temp table involved I cant use function so have created SP.

I want to "Select IP,GetHostNameForDnsTest IP from Test ". Basically passing dynamically IP to stored procedure and need to return IP and Name through stored procedure.

```
IP              NAME
192.200.22.173  ABC
0.0.0.0         XYZ
```

I am trying to create function to achieve this as below. But i am getting error message like this --Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetHostNameForDnsTest(@ip varchar(50))
RETURNS  @IPNAME TABLE 
(
    [IPNAME] varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

 
DECLARE @xpCmd VARCHAR(100)
Declare @returnVal varchar(100)
declare @InternalIP as varchar(50)
set @InternalIP=@ip

SET @xpCmd = 'NSLOOKUP ' + @ip
declare @Test table (nslookup_out NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Test
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @xpCmd

Insert into  @IPNAME 
select LTRIM(REPLACE(nslookup_out, 'Name:', '')) name  FROM @Test
where nslookup_out like 'Name: %'
 

RETURN
END
```

Comment: using SQL server management studio 2018

Comment: create proc a @ip nvarchar(Max) as select * from yourtable where [ip]=@ip

Comment: _Because of temp table involved_ Maybe you don't actually need temp table - but no one can offer suggestions without seeing code. If a temp table must be part of the solution, the [arrays and lists](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) discussion in Erland's site discusses options.

Comment: My recollection is that a SQL function *can* use a temp table just as it uses any other table.  That is, it can read it but not write to it.  Also, the name of the table has to be pre-defined (it can’t be a variable or parameter).